# Where are the missing shortcuts of the Start menu?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, start-menu

Using W10 21H2.

Start menu shortcuts are usually located in two folders:

- `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
- `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

So customizing the Start menu is usually a matter of organizing the content of these folders. However there are entries in the Start menu without shortcuts at these places:

Examples:

[image]

These shortcuts are from MS (green) and also from the computer manufacturer (magenta). The lack of shortcuts prevent me to customize the Start menu the usual way.

Any suggestion about where to find the missing shortcuts?

Comment: That is a personal thing as you can organize the icons as you wish.  I put key office items on my desktop for easy rearrangement

Comment: To find the shortcut, right click, select More, and the File location. The shortcut is there

Comment: @John: "*To find the shortcut, right click, select More, and the File location. The shortcut is there*" oh that's what I can't find. Perhaps I don't look at the right place, do you see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuX3g.png)?

Comment: It varies. Try right clicking and opening file location in the resulting menu (may be a long menu). Microsoft is apparently adjusting this.

Comment: You're getting close votes because you repeatedly mention a topic that is only tangentially related to your actual question. Your question is "where are these shortcuts located, and can I move them somewhere else." Mentioning rearranging things is what's attracting the close votes, and it's not the problem you're actually trying to solve. I'd suggest editing your question to focus on the root problem.

Comment: @music2myear: Thanks for the comment, yes I realize my question is not very well stated and needs to be clarified.